# I can't access this wordpress function get_post in my classes

Tags: php, wordpress

It looks like I can't access these wordpress functions in my classes
I'm trying to call the `get_post` function in a class but it keep returning null
I've also tried global `$post` and it also returns null
I tried calling it with the `init` life cycle action but it's still returning null
Any ideas of how to make this work?

```
namespace Maid_Brigade;
class Franchise {

    protected $post;

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', [ $this, 'init' ] );
    }

    public function get_email_recipients() {
        return $this->get_block_attribute('recipients');
    }

    public function get_block_attribute( $attribute ) {
        $post = $this->post;
        $attribute_value = null;
        $blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content );
        var_dump($post); // returns null

        // foreach code... 
        return $attribute_value;
    }

    public function init() {
        $this->post = get_post();
        var_dump($this->post); // returns null 
    }
}

// Instantiated in functions.php
$maid_brigade_franchise = new Maid_Brigade\Franchise();
$maid_brigade_franchise->get_email_recipients();
```

Comment: You're supposed to pass a post ID to get_post(), I think. If `$_GLOBALS['post']` is set it is used instead. Null means the post wasn't found.

Comment: You are not running it inside a post.

Comment: Init is too early, no request or post data has been set yet.

Answer (score 1):

I realized I would have to call these functions on a specific wordpress hook `wp` in order to have access to the post object.

```
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp', [ $this, 'init' ] );
    }

    public function get_block_attribute( $attribute ) {
        add_action( 'wp', function () {
            $attribute_value = null;
            $blocks = parse_blocks( $this->current_post->post_content );
            var_dump($this->current_post); // returns WP_Post

            foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {
                if ( $block['attrs']['data'][$attribute] ) {
                    $attribute_value = $block['attrs']['data'][$attribute];
                    break;
                }
            }
            return $attribute_value;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Initialize plugin
     */
    public function init() {
        $this->current_post = get_post();
        var_dump($this->current_post); // returns WP_Post 
    }
```